# pushing object to array in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, push

i have a problem with pushing object to array.. i want a result like this..
`[{b:"a"},{b:"c"}]`

with this code

```
const [list, setList] - useState({occupation_id: ""});

const handleAdd = () => {
    let arr = [];
    const newData = {...list};
    newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    arr.push(newData);
    setList(arr);
}
```

but the result from the code below is

`[{{occupation_id: "2"}, occupation_id: "1"}]`

what the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it easily with this solution, Try this:

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]); // your initial data
const handleAdd = () => {
 setList([...list, {e.target.id:e.target.value}]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]);
const handleAdd = () => {
 setList([...list, {[e.target.id]:e.target.value}]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [list, setList] = useState([{occupation_id: "1"}, {occupation_id: "2"}]);

  const handleAdd = (id, value) => {
    const newData = [...list]  
    newData.push({id, value});
    setList(newData);
    console.log(newData)
}
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained what was happening,

Comment: Pushing into array better than replace into array index and make a copy from prev object as array.

Comment: [Edit] to update instead of commenting, please.

Answer (score 0):

Define state like an array: this works

```
const [list, setList] = useState([{occupation_id: "2"}]);

const handleAdd = (e) => setList([...list, { e.target.name: e.target.value }])
```